# Django Moving an object from one database to another

Tags: python, django, postgresql, sqlite, django-models

I am trying to migrate from `SQLite` to `postgreSQL` after trying `Django` builtin command `dumpdata` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35539241/getting-django-db-utils-integrityerror-when-migrating-data-from-sqlite-to-postgr)

Found another way in the official docs, The data is migrated without any error but when I am trying to save instance of any Model via `shell or form` I am getting `pk` already exist error. Somehow `django` isn't aware of existing values . . . .

```
for firm in models.Firm.objects.using("olddb").all():
    firm.save(using="default")
```

Now `default database` has all the objects from the `olddb`

```
>>> Firm.objects.all()[0]
<Firm: ABC>
>>> Firm.objects.all()[0].id
1
>>> f = Firm()
>>> f.name = "ABDEGVHG"
>>> f.save(using="default")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\vaibh\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 590, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "C:\Users\vaibh\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 618, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "C:\Users\vaibh\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 699, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "C:\Users\vaibh\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 732, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "C:\Users\vaibh\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 92, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\vaibh\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 921, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "C:\Users\vaibh\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 920, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\vaibh\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\vaibh\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "C:\Users\vaibh\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\six.py", line 549, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\vaibh\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "girvi_firm_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) already exists.
```

Can someone please tell me how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by `SELECT setval('girvi_firm_id_seq', max(id)) FROM girvi_firm;` @apollo13 on #django IRC suggested me to update the sequence and it worked. Thanks to him